# Why the macros in Objective-C / Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macros

I'm coming from a place without macros (Java/Python/C#/Scala) so perhaps my perspective is distorted but...

Why are macros used in Cocoa? Two that spring to mind are `NSLocalizedString` and `NSAssert` (and `STAssert`). Would it be so hard / unsuitable to make them functions (which could be inlined)? I suppose I find them a little bizarre as an unnecessary throw-back to C (and yes, I am familiar with the pedigree of Obj-C).

Is it just something that was done back in the day or is there a specific reason?

Comment: what is the problem with macros? Are macros the new `goto` evil?

Comment: not this again -.- `goto`is not evil when applied in a proper manner. In some cases it leads to much cleaner code than using other things (e.g. breaking out of several while, if, for, etc. at once. Often the code should be split up in more methods and return used, but `goto` definitely has it's places if one knows what he is doing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general it is preferable to avoid macros, but for functionality like that provided by `NSAssert()`, you can't.

If you look at the definition, you'll see that it uses `__LINE__`, `__FILE__`, `_cmd` and `self` from the context it is used in. If it wasn't a macro, it wouldn't have access to that information.

For `NSLocalizedString` however, i see no obvious reason.

Comment: I suppose `NSLocalizedString` needs also to access `__LINE__` or `__FILE__` in cases of ambiguity.

Comment: The Cocoa-version just maps to message passing to `[NSBundle mainBundle]`, so i don't see it. @Deb

Comment: Yes, for `NSLocalizedString` there doesn't seem to be much interesting going on except a function argument re-write.

Comment: NSLocalizedString is actually nice that it is a macro because when defining global NSString const * variables you can initialize them with a value and still get the genstrings exe to translate the names.  I have two include files that "turn off/on" the NSLocalizedString that I #include around these global variables or arrays.  I have a fairly complex application in 16 different languages and this has been very helpful.

Comment: @Brent: But you could just as well use a macro `MyLocalizedString` that maps to either of these. I'd say this is less confusing than redefining a Cocoa macro :) Looking into it, it is also documented as a function - so technically i don't think it is guaranteed that it stays a macro.

Answer (score 4):

NSLocalizedString is a convenience macro and could probably be made a function.

However, there are good reasons why NSAssert and friends are macros besides the one given in Georg's answer.  NSAssert evaluates a boolean expression to determine whether an exception should be thrown.  That boolean expression might be quite computationally expensive and not the sort of thing you want to happen in your release code.  There's no mechanism in C (and therefore Objective-C) of omitting normal function calls for a release build without resorting to the preprocessor or perhaps using stuff like:

```
if (debug)
{
    assertAsAFunction(foo == 3, "foo should be 3");
}
```

Another advantage of the NSAssert macro is that the condition can be stringified for use in a log message.